# How to delay Auto Start in Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-16

How can I delay the auto start in Wildfly16? I see that there is an option for entering any expression in the field, not just true/false. What should I write in there to delay the start of a Server by let's say 10 minutes? I can't find any information about this field in the documentation.

Comment: How do you start WildFly?

Comment: When we start/restart our Windows server the Wildfly service starts automatically, in Wildfly we have the Auto Start enabled for the instances. I would like to start the instances with delay, and this can only be done in Wildfly, or of course from a script, but I hoped there is a built-in mechanism for this feature.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to do this. I don't really know much about Windows services. However, the startup scripts themselves have no way to delay starting. It would really just a best guess anyway. It seems you'd want a way to know say the DB has started before WildFly does. That is out of the scope of WildFly though.